# How to add a css class on range slider interval using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to add a CSS class to an element when a range slider *changes value*? For instance I have a slider like so:

```
 <input id="slider" type="range" min="10" max="50">
```

I also have JavaScript to get the value, and divide by 10, like so:

```
let sliderValue = Number(slider.value);
sliderValue = Math.ceil(sliderValue / 10);

//gives:
3
2
1
2
3
4
5 etc. on slider input.
```

I want to add a class called `active` to an element on the page which fades in an element when the slider changes value. Since this slider is performing a function 10 times per interval, is there a way to have JS "listen" for when the slider changes value and apply a class then?

---

Currently, the "active" class gets applied 10 times per interval and it stutters. Here's a CodePen showing my problem: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/wvGgJqN)

Comment: you want a fade out / in on any change on your slider or what ??

Comment: Not just on any change, but I'm asking to see if the change can fade in / out when the slider value changes from `1` to `2` to `3`. Currently, it's applying a class on `10 11 12 13` all the way to `50`. Does that make sense?

Comment: you mean you want to have -for example- 3 fade out / in if the value of the slider changes by 3 values at once?

Comment: why `colorSeven.value` is `2` ?

Comment: It's just an arbitrary number.

Comment: well, and what about my previous question ? ( 3 fade out/in)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your question. I want the "fade in" effect to happen when a value transitions from 3 to 4 or 3 to 2, for example. Imagine instead of changing abruptly, they fade a bit. I am able to achieve this when I set the `min="1" max="5"`, but the slider is not smooth. I'm trying to make the slider smooth as well, hence the math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made these modifications to make it smooth:

```js
function colorValues() {
    const colors = {
        colorOne: {
            name: "Color 1",
            value: 1
        },
        colorTwo: {
            name: "Color 2",
            value: 2
        },
        colorThree: {
            name: "Color 3",
            value: 3
        },
        colorFour: {
            name: "Color 4",
            value: 3
        },
        colorFive: {
            name: "Color 5",
            value: 4
        },
        colorSix: {
            name: "Color 6",
            value: 5
        },
        colorSeven: {
            name: "Color 7",
            value: 2
        }
    };

    const slider = document.querySelector("#slider");

    const refresh = (dataSet) => {
        let output = document.querySelector("#results");
        output.innerHTML = "";
        dataSet.forEach((d) => {
            output.innerHTML = `<div class="result">
      <h3>${d.name}</h3>
      <p>Color Value Number: ${d.value}</p>
      </div>`;
        });

        function fadeIn() {
            let results = document.querySelectorAll(".result");
            results.forEach((result) => {
                result.classList.add("active");
            });
        }
        window.setTimeout(fadeIn, 0);
    };

    const filter = () => {
        let data = Object.values(colors);
        let sliderValue = Number(slider.value);
        sliderValue = Math.ceil(sliderValue / 10);
        let filteredData = data.filter((d) => d.value === sliderValue);

        refresh(filteredData);
    };

    slider.addEventListener("input", filter);
}

colorValues();
```

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50vw;
    margin: 5rem auto;
    background: #444;
    color: #f5f5f5;
}

.result {
    margin-top: 4rem;
    background: #c4c4c4;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: block;
    color: #444;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.active {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<p>Goal: to get slider to be smooth.</p>
<input id="slider" type="range" min="10" max="50" />
<label for="slider">Slide me</label>
<section id="results"></section>
```

Comment: I had that going previously, but I want to see if I can make it fade in when a new "color card" is shown. So, the desired result would be a brief fade in when a new result is shown.

Comment: I see. It will be hard to get the desired effect if I understand you correctly due the nature of the way the slider works. You can't restrict the speed at which a user moves it, so have any fading effects would be flickery by nature. Do you have an example of this effect being used somewhere else?

Comment: Currently on our live site, the values are from the min and max go from 1 to 5, so you get big jumps between values and it doesn't feel good from a UX perspective. I'm really just trying to have my cake and eat it too. Worst case scenario, I'll revert back to your solution. I was hoping there was something in JS that could listen to the mutation of the value.